# Every time that I import RtcEngine into my application (import RtcEngine from 'react-native-agora';) I get the following error:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, agora.io

**    TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'AgoraRtcChannelModule.prefix')
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in
ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at node_modules@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:62:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:288:29 in invoke
at node_modules@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:62:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:152:27 in invoke
at node_modules@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:162:18 in
Promise.resolve.then$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in
setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in
__guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue**

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show us yout code and describe what you have tried so far and what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

look like the library is not linked well,
try:
first console.log the library to see if it you get the import well.
second try to do fresh build:

- clean project
- delete node_modules
- yarn
- check your node version
- cd ios
- pod deintegrate
- pod install
- sometimes deleting the app and re build it do the magic